# Get_cli initializing a new project structure fails with new Flutter 3.19.4

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, get-cli

**1) GetX Pattern (by Kauê)**

**2) CLEAN (by Arktekko)**
Which architecture do you want to use? [1]

**Unhandled exception:**
Synchronous waiting using dart:cli waitFor and C API Dart_WaitForEvent is deprecated and disabled by default. This feature will be fully removed in Dart 3.4 release. You can currently still enable it by passing --enable_deprecated_wait_for to the Dart VM. See https://dartbug.com/52121